# Compressing/Expanding JavaFX 2 data chart

Tags: charts, javafx-2, line-plot

Having a XY Line Chart I would like compress/expand data visualization both for X and Y axis by left mouse click, keep pressed and drag left/right and up/down.

Here is a chart example

[image]

and here is the code to plot sample data

```
public class BaseXYChart extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
   stage.setTitle("Linear plot");

   final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
   final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(1, 22, 0.5);

   yAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(yAxis){
        @Override
    public String toString(Number object){
        return String.format("%7.2f", object);
    }
});
final LineChart<String, Number>lineChart = new LineChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

   lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);
   lineChart.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
   lineChart.setLegendVisible(false);

   XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();

    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jan", 1));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Feb", 1.5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mar", 2));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Apr", 2.5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("May", 3));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jun", 4));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Jul", 6));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Aug", 9));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Sep", 12));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Oct", 15));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Nov", 20));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Dec", 22));

    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setCenter(lineChart);          
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 600);
    lineChart.getData().addAll(series1);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}   
}
```

How can I accomplish this? I haven't found any examples anywhere!

Thanks.

Add picture

[image: Result after left mouse click, pressed and drag on Y Axis from top to bottom]

Result after left mouse click, pressed and drag on Y Axis from top to bottom

Same result should be for X Axis to get a compressed line data by left/right mouse drag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, perhaps you could use something like the following which will resize the chart based on clicking and dragging on the axes.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.effect.Effect;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DraggableAxisResizableChart extends Application {
  private static final int UNDEFINED = -1;
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart(
      xAxis, yAxis,
      FXCollections.observableArrayList(
         new XYChart.Series("April", FXCollections.observableArrayList(
           new XYChart.Data(0, 4), new XYChart.Data(1, 10), new XYChart.Data(2, 18), new XYChart.Data(3, 15)
         ))
      )      
    );
    chart.setPrefSize(400, 300);
    chart.setMaxSize(400, 300);
    makeXAxisDraggable(xAxis, chart);
    makeYAxisDraggable(yAxis, chart);

    StackPane layout = new StackPane();
    layout.getChildren().add(chart);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(layout, 800, 600));
    stage.show();
  }

  private void makeXAxisDraggable(final NumberAxis xAxis, final LineChart<Number, Number> chart) {
    final Delta d = new Delta();
    xAxis.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        if (d.x == UNDEFINED) {
          d.x = event.getSceneX(); 
          d.y = event.getSceneY();
        } else { 
          chart.setMaxHeight(
            chart.getPrefHeight() * (
              (chart.getPrefHeight() + (event.getSceneY() - d.y) * 2) / chart.getPrefHeight()
            )
          );
        }  
      }
    });

    xAxis.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        d.x = UNDEFINED; d.y = UNDEFINED;
        chart.setPrefSize(chart.getMaxWidth(), chart.getMaxHeight());
      }
    });

    addMouseoverGlow(xAxis);
  }

  private void makeYAxisDraggable(final NumberAxis yAxis, final LineChart<Number, Number> chart) {
    final Delta d = new Delta();
    yAxis.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        if (d.x == -1) {
          d.x = event.getSceneX(); 
          d.y = event.getSceneY();
        } else { 
          chart.setMaxWidth(
            chart.getPrefWidth() * (
              (chart.getPrefWidth() - (event.getSceneX() - d.x) * 2) / chart.getPrefWidth()
            )
          );
        }  
      }
    });

    yAxis.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        d.x = UNDEFINED; d.y = UNDEFINED;
        chart.setPrefSize(chart.getMaxWidth(), chart.getMaxHeight());
      }
    });

    addMouseoverGlow(yAxis);
  }

  // create a glow feedback effect on a node when the mouse is hovered over it.
  private void addMouseoverGlow(final Node n) {
    final Effect glow = new DropShadow(10, Color.GOLDENROD);
    n.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        n.setEffect(glow);
      }
    });
    n.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        n.setEffect(null);
      }
    });
  }

  // records a relative point location.
  class Delta { double x = UNDEFINED, y = UNDEFINED; }
}
```

An alternate implementation could use a scale on the node.

The implementation above leaves slight ghost trails as the graph is resized, so you may want to fix that up somehow, if the example proves useful.

Comment: Thanks jewelsea, your works is great but I think I did not explain correctly what I need to achieve:
once data is plotted ( for data I mean the line data plotted), by left mouse click, keep pressed and drag left/right on X axis the line itself should expand / compress (i.e. magnify) while the chart remain the same 800,600 dimension.
The scene will not change as dimensions, only we will have a line plot changed. Will try to add a picture so to be more clear

Comment: Thought I was missing something ;-) I think you might want to look into setting the [range](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.html#setRange%28java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) upon drag detection.  Drag detection logic should be similar to the example I provided, but you will be scaling the max/min range values rather than the chart size.

Comment: Thank jewelsea,I will try to modify your code as your suggestion